# Is it possible to obtain high-level enchantments in MCBE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing on a Creative world in MCBE, and mess around with everything. I got the idea to obtain a Looting 32 sword using commands, but it errors out and says that the max level is 3. I tried using these methods, but all have failed:

```
/give @s diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:21,lvl:32}]}
/enchant @s looting 32
```

Is there any way to obtain a high level enchantment using commands, without editing the game code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I obtain items that exceed their maximum enchantment level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290467/how-can-i-obtain-items-that-exceed-their-maximum-enchantment-level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in Vanilla, but if you tinker around with the max enchantment levels I think you might be able to get something.