# How do I get Iron golem spawner on Minecraft PE 1.15

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need a iron golem spawner for my iron farm. Is there a command(setblock or give) to give me a mob spawner that spawns iron golems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use an NBT editor to modify item properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/how-do-i-use-an-nbt-editor-to-modify-item-properties)

Comment: I disagree that either of those questions are relevant. By my reading of the question, the user only wants to get the item once, not through the action of a command block run multiple times.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, neither of your suggestions work here @ExpertCoder14 -- they both rely on the player already having access to such a block that they can then copy or clone.

Comment: @Schism I stand corrected—my previous comment was based off the incorrect assumption that a spawn egg exists for iron golems. They don’t.

Comment: @pppery But I disagree that this is a duplicate anyway: the post for modifying item data with an NBT editor does not have instructions for changing spawner data. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Anyways, I play Minecraft on my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

This is not achievable in Minecraft Bedrock Edition in-game.
If you're using Windows 10 and willing to use third-party software you can check out [using an NBT Editor to modify item properties](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376578/258509) and use those skills to modify the spawner if you put it in the chest.

Comment: The give command does not work properly it just gives the player a pig spawner.

Comment: Is this for Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Comment: I can also use a command block

Comment: @user260555 i'm super smart and thought this was java, read the edited answer

Answer (score -2):

If you are playing on Java Edition, you can use this useful site right [here](https://www.digminecraft.com/generators/mob_spawner_1_15.php). It's a Monster Spawner Generator that generates command for the spawner that you need, with some spesific details if you want. But if you are playing on Bedrock Edition, sorry, I don't think there's any command to that.