# How can I make a tool unbreakable?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have looked everywhere for a command that does the same thing as:

```
/give @s netherite_sword{unbreakable:1} 1
```

but for Bedrock Edition instead of Java Edition. But I just can't seem to find an answer anywhere. There hasn't been anything that has told me it's not possible. But all of the answers I find only pertain to the Java Edition of Minecraft. Even the Minecraft Wiki does not have any different answer for Bedrock Edition.

Comment: This might be able to be done with an [NBT Editor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376578/258509)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use an NBT editor to modify item properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/how-do-i-use-an-nbt-editor-to-modify-item-properties) (note that I came to the same conclusion independently of Penguin)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you can't really do this with a single command, because in Bedrock Edition, there is no such JSON component for enchanting using the `/give` command.

So it's better to just do:

1. `/give netherite_sword`
2. `/enchant unbreaking 3` (whilst holding sword)

> Optional enchantment: `/enchant mending`

Also, to put it simply, you cannot really have an unbreakable item. This requires an NBT editor, which means getting the sword (or something else) to be unbreakable by a higher level of Unbreaking.