# Minecraft Anvil Enchanted Item adding

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In minecraft I have a sharpness 5 Netherite Axe is it possible for me to put it in an anvil, add a Smite 5 Netherite Axe and get a Sharpness 5 Smite 5 Netherite Axe, and then put it in anvil again put a BoA 5 Netherite Axe and then get a Sharpness 5, Smite 5, BoA 5 Netherite Axe?

Answer (score 2):

The Minecraft Wiki states that Sharpness, Smite, and Bane of Arthropods are mutually exclusive. So no, you cannot add more than one of those types of enchantments to your sword.

If you're willing to use cheats, you can [use an NBT editor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/376577/250180) to get the enchantments on an item.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you cannot add Smite on an item with Sharpness, nor Bane of Arthropods.

It's better to just have 2 swords (yes, swords, not axes) as they deal more damage in Bedrock Edition, 1 with Sharpness and 1 with Smite. Smite for certain hostile mobs, and Sharpness for others.