# Is there a way to enchant armor a player is wearing?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm setting up a killer gamemode and I would like the killer to have armor with curse of binding on it. I'm triggering the transformation with a single button attached to multiple command blocks. Is there any way to do the this? (The enchantment portion.)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly how to enchant armor being worn by a player, but maybe you could use an [NBT editor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/how-do-i-use-an-nbt-editor-to-modify-item-properties), but this doesn't really change anything, because you are not wearing it. I don't know how to reimplement this but maybe you could use `/enchant` and `/replaceitem` in command blocks. I don't really know how to make it.

Answer (score 1):

*Just an idea:*

First clear the player of his chestplate
(Clear Command)

Then Clone/Setblock the blocks like this:
(Clone/Setblock/Execute Commands)

&
%
@
@

@=Player %=Dispenser with enchanted chestplate facing Down &=Redstone Block

Then Remove it using fill and don't let it drop the items.
(Fill/Execute Commands)

This is not a clean solution, but I had to do something similar when setting up a red vs blue minigame and I wanted each team to have colored helmets. I cloned a chest at a set location to be above the player, with the dyed helmet in it. Then I broke it with a setblock command with destroy at the end. To adapt it to your case I would clear the chestplate then do the rest. You could also use a dispenser and activate it then remove it. This would put it on his chest slot. (I haven't played Bedrock Edition on a computer just on a Mobile Device and it's been a while so I don't know the exact syntax.)

The syntax would look something like this assuming you tag the killer with /tag @p add Killer.

```
/clear @a[tag=Killer] (Chestplate ID)
/execute @a[tag=Killer] ~~~ clone (x y z of dispencer) (x y z of dispencer) ~~2~ 
/execute @a[tag=Killer] ~~~ setblock ~~3~ redstone_block
/execute @a[tag=Killer] ~~~ fill ~~2~ ~~3~ air
```

- Sorry, my other answer was typed on the spot but this one should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to enchant items not held by the player, but the minimal BE NBT available allows you to give items which are "locked" in their slot.

> `lock_in_slot`
>
> Prevents the item from being moved or removed from its slot in the player's inventory, dropped, or crafted with.

From [Item Components](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_components) on the Minecraft Fandom wiki.

So, to set the armor of a player to an undroppable diamond chestplate...

```
replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.chest 0 diamond_chestplate 1 0 {"minecraft:item_lock":{"mode":"lock_in_slot"}}
```

See [/replaceitem command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/replaceitem) and [Slot](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slot#Command_argument_2).