# How do I use replace item in Minecraft Bedrock with enchantments?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been trying to learn commands and it's been a struggle so I'm looking for help trying to find out how to use the replace item command with enchanted items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to enchant armor a player is wearing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/382779/is-there-a-way-to-enchant-armor-a-player-is-wearing)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to use `/replaceitem` with enchanted items. Currently, `/give` and `/replaceitem` don't support NBT editing within the command like they do in Java Edition.

Instead, you must use the `/enchant` command separately. As an example, you can simulate the command you're looking by using `/replaceitem` immediately followed by `/enchant`.