# Minecraft Bedrock Edition addons and NBT data

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

How can I make my custom blocks "have" NBT data, such as damage values, or full blown custom NBT tags?  My specific case is adding a "luck" component to my custom block, which can be anywhere between `-100` and `100`, and depending on that value, when placed and broken in the world, would do something different, for example, if the value is positive, it would drop a diamond, when it's negative it would summon primed tnt, and if it's zero it would create a dirt hut. I think I can work those out, but I first need my block to be able to store data.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use NBT tags in commands in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/is-it-possible-to-use-nbt-tags-in-commands-in-minecraft-bedrock-edition)

Comment: @Corsaka Are you sure? Accessing NBT tags in commands is much different than accessing them through other means. The proposed duplicate only takes account if the user is using commands, which they are open to other methods too.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 As in, datapacks, or something else? Wouldn't those be out of scope for this website?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use an NBT editor to modify item properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/how-do-i-use-an-nbt-editor-to-modify-item-properties)

Comment: This is asking about addons. Both @aphid's and Corsaka's duplicate both don't apply here

Comment: @Corsaka this is about addons not datapacks or commands

Comment: @Corsaka For your information Java Edition datapacks are not off-topic.

Comment: @Corsaka Unfortunately, the post you linked to doesn't quite solve my problems - I'm looking to create an addon that has a custom block that can hold a "luck" variable, an integer from `-100` to `+100`, both in the world and as an item in an inventory, and when the block is broken, should take into account the value regarding what happens afterwards.

Comment: I'm currently thinking of 2 possible solutions, either a custom component, or recycle the block's `damage` NBT. I would prefer a custom component, so as to not "pollute" the vanilla stuff, but recycling the `damage` seems more plausible.

Comment: Pls reopen this! It's a great question!

Comment: Does a nbt editor work?

Comment: @Redstoner1635 I haven't tried, but with my short while trying out addon making, I believe I would still have problems getting and setting that custom NBT, even if an external editor works.