# How do I fix Universal Minecraft Editor's broken chunk locator?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, universal-minecraft-editor

The Universal Minecraft Editor allows users to edit many different parts of their world, including the  NBT of items, entities, and blocks. It is commonly used to [edit NBT data of items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376578/250180).

However, the 1.16.100 update of Minecraft Bedrock Edition has broken the editor's Chunk Locator. Instead, the Chunk Locator shows a blank white canvas and I am unable to select a chunk to edit:

[image: UMCE Chunk Locator Empty]

If you still attempt to select a chunk and hit the "Open" button, no luck, the following error appears:

[image: UMCE Chunk Locator Error Message]

This seems to only happen in worlds that are 1.16.100+. Older worlds will still open properly.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## Notice
>
> Unfortunately, this method no longer works. There are currently no more workarounds, so Universal Minecraft Editor remains broken with no fixes.
>
> I personally do not continue to use UMCE due to the developer having somewhat extreme political views, making them a developer I do not wish to support. Therefore I do not continue to provide support for UMCE.
>
> You can edit general world data with a MCJE NBT editor such as NBTStudio, and for items, you can use structures and behaviour packs. Both methods I am familiar with, and if demand suggests they would benefit from being posted here, I will do so.

## Original answer

It was only a minor change that caused the Chunk Locator to break in 1.16.100. This minor change was the moving of the `ChunkVersion` tag to a different location, from byte 177 to byte 44. See the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_level_format#Chunk_key_format) for source.

Unfortunately, after emailing Matt G (oPryzeLP), he does not plan to fix the software, due to it being unpaid for.

But, all is not lost. I am happy to inform you that after speaking with Tryashtar on the Minecraft Commands Discord server, they have come up with a solution!

They have now rigged up their Image Map editor to, in addition to reading maps of your world, it will also restore the legacy `ChunkVersion` tag that is required for UMCE to work.

Just click on the Bedrock World button and click on the world you want to open. This will then automatically add back the legacy chunks.

You can get the file [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/e23lw6i5i2udakq/ImageMap3.zip/file).

Comment: I just tried this, and it didn't seem to work. Did something change?

Comment: @Pikatchoo32 Yes, MCBE is constantly changing. This was a temporary solution that was very janky. It doesn't surprise me that this is broken, and I doubt it'll ever work again.

Comment: Too bad, hopefully the new editor that Matt's working on can pull off all the same stuff.