# In bedrock edition, how do you get fortune 100,000 on a pick without mods? I'm ready to cheat in a pick at this point

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm ok with cheating in one, but I can't get mods with the way I get my Minecraft.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use an NBT editor to modify item properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/how-do-i-use-an-nbt-editor-to-modify-item-properties)

Comment: Yeah, using an NBT editor is the way to go. Get a pick with any fortune level and edit it,

Comment: I think VSCode now has an NBT editor plugin (which means there's no plugin VSCode doesn't have anymore).

Comment: Hey, Tim Post! Found your keys yet?