# How to get a knockback 1000 stick with commands on Minecraft Education Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I have been trying to do this one can cant! Can anyone help?

Comment: What command have you tried? Please add that to your post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use an NBT editor to modify item properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/how-do-i-use-an-nbt-editor-to-modify-item-properties)