# How do I make a painting invincible?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

How do I make a painting unable to be broken? I am open to commands, addons, or even external programs if needed. The only way I have found is using weakness on players however I need them to be able to hit other players.

Note that paintings cannot have effects, at least via the `/effect` command.

To be clear intentional "griefers" aren't an issue, I'm making a map and the issue is since it uses a lot of painting secret entrances its super easy to accidentally break it and theres no way to put it back so if someone messes up their world they would have to go and manually repair it everytime it happens.

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting to check the game version. It looks like you have already answered something similar, how come does that not work? (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/how-do-i-use-an-nbt-editor-to-modify-item-properties)

Comment: @BunnyMerz LevelDB editing does not work. I even made my own NBT editor and NBT reader and writer and when I started using the LevelDB thought I was doing it right. Got to the end and voila it works! Until you open Minecraft, and as pointed out at the top of that answer, all the data reverts that had to do with the LevelDB, I'm not even sure how as the data was definitely overwritten I think with logs or something, and I and apparently tons of other people don't know how to fix it, unless I'm doing something way wrong.

Answer (score -2):

The only way to do this reliably on Bedrock (even with Add-ons) is to use a 3rd-party server software.
Even then, it is still possible for griefers to cheat and cause problems within your world.